# Is there a way to get a Dojo Dialog to popup from a PopupMenuItem to the left?

Tags: menu, dojo, dialog, popup

I'm using Dojo version 1.6.1.  I'm building a menu that has a Dialog dijit as a popup from a PopupMenuItem.  This works, however, if the menu is docked on the right-hand side of the application I need the popup to display to the left of the menu.  I can't seem to get this to work.  If I use another type of widget (like a ColorPalette), this works fine.  With popup submenus and a popup ColorPalette, everything opens to the left if the menu is on the right-hand side of the screen, and everything opens to the right if the menu is on the left-hand side of the screen.  Dojo just handles this automatically.  But with any Dialog widget, even an empty one, it always pops out to the right of the PopupMenuItem regardless of where the menu is on the screen.  I thought that perhaps specifying height and width of the div that is the dijit.Dialog would resolve this, but it did not.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Menu" id="toolPalette" style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0; z-index: 999;">
</div>

<script>
    // Grab the div for the menu, declared in the HTML above.
    var toolPalette = dijit.byId("toolPalette");

    // This tool button has a popup
    var menuItem1 = new dijit.PopupMenuItem({
        id: "menuItem1",
        iconClass: "shelterIcon",
        popup: new dijit.Dialog()
    });
    toolPalette.addChild(menuItem1);

    // This tool button does not have a popup
    var menuItem2 = new dijit.MenuItem({
        id: "menuItem2",
        iconClass: "shelterIcon"
    });
    toolPalette.addChild(menuItem2);

    toolPalette.startup();
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Way to find your current Cursor location

```
document.onmouseup = getXY;
var mouseX, mouseY;

function getXY(e) {
    mouseX= (e || event).clientX;
    mouseY= (e || event).clientY;
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
        mouseY= mouseY+ document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
}
```

Your Code here .

```
 var myDialog = new dijit.Dialog();
 var menuItem1 = new dijit.PopupMenuItem({
        id: "menuItem1",
        iconClass: "shelterIcon",
        popup: myDialog 
    });
```

Now apply the X and Y to your Dialog.

```
dijit.popup.open({
    x: mouseX,
    y : mouseY,
    popup: myDialog 
 });
```

Comment: I played around with dijit.popup.open a little but wasn't completely successful.  Are you saying that I would specify the popup property of the PopupMenuItem and do the dijit.popup.open?  I think what I tried was just using a MenuItem and calling dijit.popup.open in response to the click event, but it wasn't positioning correctly.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: I'm not having any luck with that.  Can you be more explicit about when I would call dijit.popup.open?  As you might expect, the JavaScript to build the menu is run when the page is first loaded, but the user shouldn't see the popup until menuItem1 is clicked on.  I tried putting the call to dijit.popup.open into an onClick handler, but it's still showing in the same location as before, presumably because it's still specified in the popup property of the PopupMenuItem.  I'm still stuck if you can clarify your suggestion.

Comment: @PaulAngelno did you try to call the getXY() onClick of the MenuItem